# Icefaces combined css not loading initially

Tags: css, jsf-2, icefaces

I have an application that when I first open the page, all the styles are loaded but one, the combined.css.jspx from icefaces, and the layout is wrong. When I hit F5 and reload the page this css is loaded and the page layout is correct!

Anyone have a clue on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I bet you have an error in either the client or server logging

Comment: No error in any log... I checked that.

Comment: not even a 404 or 500 or...

Comment: Nothing. It just doesn't load the css files the first time I enter the pages. When I reload (F5, post, etc) all the css files are loaded correctly.